# Why lxml (Python Lib) doesn't parse Signature node using objectify.fromstring(xml_string)?

Tags: python, lxml

I'm using [lxml](http://lxml.de/index.html) lib to parse XML(My XML file uses XML Signature) to python object, everything works except just one case, the xml model below the `Signature` tag is not parsed to Object.

```
from lxml import etree,objectify
xml_object = objectify.fromstring(xml_string)

# This works
xml_object.infNFe

#This doesn't works, raise the exception that Signature attribute is not defined
xml_object.Signature
```

PyCharm debug, the `Signature tag` was not parsed

[image]

Curiosity, if I try to parse ONLY `Signature` tag it works, but if the it's together with others, it doesn't works.

I've looked the website about this issue but I didn't find any solution!

So, the question is, how to parse the whole XML below?

**The XML used**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NFe>
   <infNFe Id="NFe24151011111111111111550010000000301973817012" versao="3.10">
      <ide>
         <cUF>24</cUF>
         <cNF>97381701</cNF>
         <natOp>Venda de produto do estabelecimento</natOp>
         <indPag>0</indPag>
         <mod>55</mod>
         <serie>1</serie>
         <nNF>30</nNF>
         <dhEmi>2015-10-08T15:38:45-03:00</dhEmi>
         <dhSaiEnt>2015-10-08T15:38:45-03:00</dhSaiEnt>
         <tpNF>1</tpNF>
         <idDest>1</idDest>
         <cMunFG>2408003</cMunFG>
         <tpImp>1</tpImp>
         <tpEmis>1</tpEmis>
         <cDV>2</cDV>
         <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
         <finNFe>1</finNFe>
         <indFinal>0</indFinal>
         <indPres>1</indPres>
         <procEmi>0</procEmi>
         <verProc>PyComp Modulo NFe</verProc>
      </ide>
      <emit>
         <CNPJ>11111111111111</CNPJ>
         <xNome>Razão Social Ltda. EPP</xNome>
         <xFant>Nome Fantasia</xFant>
         <enderEmit>
            <xLgr>Al. Kenworthy</xLgr>
            <nro>140</nro>
            <xBairro>Jd. Santa Rosália</xBairro>
            <cMun>2408003</cMun>
            <xMun>Mossoro</xMun>
            <UF>RN</UF>
            <CEP>59600000</CEP>
            <cPais>1058</cPais>
            <fone>1534110602</fone>
         </enderEmit>
         <IE>111111111111</IE>
         <CRT>1</CRT>
      </emit>
      <dest>
         <CNPJ>11111111111111</CNPJ>
         <xNome>EMPRESA EXEMPLO LTDA</xNome>
         <enderDest>
            <xLgr>RUA NISIA FLORESTA</xLgr>
            <nro>846</nro>
            <xBairro>BOA VISTA</xBairro>
            <cMun>2408003</cMun>
            <xMun>MOSSORO</xMun>
            <UF>RN</UF>
            <cPais>1058</cPais>
            <xPais>BRASIL</xPais>
            <fone>1534110602</fone>
         </enderDest>
         <indIEDest>9</indIEDest>
         <IE>111111111111</IE>
      </dest>
      <det nItem="1">
         <prod>
            <cProd>1253236</cProd>
            <cEAN>7896297837046</cEAN>
            <xProd>Descrição do produto</xProd>
            <NCM>999999999</NCM>
            <CFOP>5102</CFOP>
            <uCom>UN</uCom>
            <qCom>100.00</qCom>
            <vUnCom>10.00</vUnCom>
            <vProd>1000.00</vProd>
            <cEANTrib>7896297837046</cEANTrib>
            <uTrib>UN</uTrib>
            <qTrib>100.00</qTrib>
            <vUnTrib>10.00</vUnTrib>
            <indTot>1</indTot>
         </prod>
         <imposto>
            <vTotTrib>18.00</vTotTrib>
            <ICMS>
               <ICMS00>
                  <orig>0</orig>
                  <CST>00</CST>
                  <modBC>3</modBC>
                  <vBC>1.00</vBC>
                  <pICMS>17.00</pICMS>
                  <vICMS>0.17</vICMS>
               </ICMS00>
            </ICMS>
         </imposto>
      </det>
      <det nItem="2">
         <prod>
            <cProd>1253236</cProd>
            <cEAN>7896297837046</cEAN>
            <xProd>PRODUTO 2</xProd>
            <NCM>999999999</NCM>
            <CFOP>5102</CFOP>
            <uCom>UN</uCom>
            <qCom>1.00</qCom>
            <vUnCom>1.00</vUnCom>
            <vProd>1.00</vProd>
            <cEANTrib>7896297837046</cEANTrib>
            <uTrib>UN</uTrib>
            <qTrib>1.00</qTrib>
            <vUnTrib>1.00</vUnTrib>
            <indTot>1</indTot>
         </prod>
         <imposto>
            <vTotTrib>18.17</vTotTrib>
            <ICMS>
               <ICMS00>
                  <orig>0</orig>
                  <CST>00</CST>
                  <modBC>3</modBC>
                  <vBC>1.00</vBC>
                  <pICMS>17.00</pICMS>
                  <vICMS>0.17</vICMS>
               </ICMS00>
            </ICMS>
         </imposto>
      </det>
      <total>
         <ICMSTot>
            <vBC>1000.00</vBC>
            <vICMS>180.00</vICMS>
            <vICMSDeson>0.00</vICMSDeson>
            <vBCST>0.00</vBCST>
            <vST>0.00</vST>
            <vProd>1000.00</vProd>
            <vFrete>0.00</vFrete>
            <vSeg>0.00</vSeg>
            <vDesc>0.00</vDesc>
            <vII>0.00</vII>
            <vIPI>0.00</vIPI>
            <vPIS>0.00</vPIS>
            <vCOFINS>0.00</vCOFINS>
            <vOutro>0.00</vOutro>
            <vNF>1100.00</vNF>
            <vTotTrib>0.00</vTotTrib>
         </ICMSTot>
      </total>
      <transp>
         <modFrete>9</modFrete>
      </transp>
   </infNFe>
   <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <SignedInfo>
         <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
         <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
         <Reference URI="#NFe24151011111111111111550010000000301973817012">
            <Transforms>
               <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
               <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>OWcT6jHwBr4c3kGNBwzFoQ03oHQ=</DigestValue>
         </Reference>
      </SignedInfo>
      <SignatureValue>BxP66jlYeNfD2JPKkUaih3gJzMvxIWWZsGDqps/lylpW55uyCl4DnK9ppdXAzKNsoRwyQz5fPE8CECSbJbkZkIth82pK0Ul7ZjWsogD6luncJ78oS+B6xFqUL3ypm5mtq+vkQOK8ljdBxAh8gYRW/V8yEMu2rTcmI1vki6PGOMnItM68e7vpJl01GLI2FwI9gLBDNjHJJ2i8snJL6waS/PHx+UOX2vYogIGbtw+y11FI0brcm056AjyIycZsEg8XByoVB7WfLVNIpCPwdDrDjMV6TOTX9MGMuoVRxAYz+7W5PEkJTU6Sd5FmHcsRkw7SeDaXGgdcBR7SIbrnOOH6zQ==</SignatureValue>
      <KeyInfo>
         <X509Data>
            <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
         </X509Data>
      </KeyInfo>
   </Signature>
</NFe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
```

There is a problem with `xmlns` attribute. `lmlx` will try to parse it as namespase. Just remove it or replace.

```
>>> print etree.tostring(xml_object.Signature, pretty_print=True)

<Signature>
  <SignedInfo>
    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
    <Reference URI="#NFe24151011111111111111550010000000301973817012">
      <Transforms>
        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
      </Transforms>
      <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
      <DigestValue>OWcT6jHwBr4c3kGNBwzFoQ03oHQ=</DigestValue>
    </Reference>
  </SignedInfo>
  <SignatureValue>...</SignatureValue>
  <KeyInfo>
    <X509Data>
      <X509Certificate>....</X509Certificate>
    </X509Data>
  </KeyInfo>
</Signature>
```

Comment: Yes, I fogot to say in my question that I tried what you said and it works, but I can't remove it, but right now I found another way the make it works, just use `getattr(xml_object, "{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}Signature")` and I can get the value of `Signature` tag, actually your answer is valid! Thank you